# if $a$ and $b$ are multiplicative unique identities, show that $a = b$ using field properties

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-explanation

A1 For all $a, b \in R,$ we have $a + b = b + a.$ (commutativity of addition)

A2 For all $a, b, c \in R,$ we have $(a + b) + c = a + (b + c).$ (associativity of addition)

A3 There is a unique element 0 ∈ R such that, for all a ∈ R, a + 0 = 0 + a = a. The
element 0 is called the additive identity.

A4 For any a ∈ R, there exists an element −a ∈ R such that a+ (−a) = 0. The elements
−a is called the additive inverse of a.

M1 For all a, b ∈ R, we have a · b = b · a. (commutativity of addition)

M2 For all a, b, c ∈ R, we have (a · b) · c = a · (b · c). (associativity of multiplication)

M3 There is a unique element 1 ∈ R such that a · 1 = 1 · a = a for all a ∈ R. The element
1 is called the multiplicative identity.

M4 For any a ∈ R, a does not equal to 0, there exists an element a^−1 ∈ R such that aa−1 = 1. The
element a^−1
is called the multiplicative inverse of a.

AM1 For any a, b, c ∈ R, we have (a + b) · c = a · c + b · c. (distributivity)

Answer (score 1):

If $a$ and $b$ are multiplicative identities, then $a=ab=b.$ The first equality holds since $b$ is an identity, the second because $a$ is.